# Algebraic proof of Liouville’s theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

Liouville’s theorem states that there are no non constant global holomorphic functions on a connected compact complex manifold. Translated into the language of algebraic geometry this becomes
$$H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \cong\mathbb{C}.$$

Where X is a compact complex manifold and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on X.

Now I know that there are several analytic proofs of this using the maximum boundedness principle, I am however interested in directly proving the above relation of global sections to obtain Liouville’s theorem algebraically. Any reference I have considered uses the analytic result to argue the algebraic identity.

I would be really thankful if anyone could provide a sheaf theoretic proof of this space of global sections being $\mathbb{C}$ (provided that there is one).

Comment: If you are asking about the result $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \Bbb C$ for $X$ an algebraic object with some nice adjectives, that can be proven in algebraic geometry. However, there is a stumbling block to recovering the literal version of your result: not every compact complex manifold can be obtained from a variety - there are non-algebraic complex tori, for instance.

Comment: Okay maybe asking for X being a general compact complex manifold is too much, I probably want to ask this for algebraic complex manifolds only or maybe the projective case is easier. I was just hoping that there was some algebraic insight to prove something like this, but maybe it’s too much to ask to do this non-analytically.

Comment: See corollary 5.3.5 in these notes: https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~kool0009/AG_notes.pdf This makes crucial use of the Zariski topology on an algebraic variety, so you do really need the complex manifold to be algebraic.